# woocommerce order Discount not showing up in Order Details receipt using points but points are redeemed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, reward-system

I am using woo-commerce points and rewards system. Problem, that I am facing is, When points are redeemed it does not show discount on order details reciept.

http://www.screencast.com/t/uAvzwhRgAlVv

[image]